# PHP cURL not taking time outs into account

Tags: php, curl

I have a simple PHP script that uses cURL to grab the contents of a URL:

```
$curlOptions = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 3,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $curlOptions );
$curlResult = curl_exec( $curl );
$status = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
curl_close( $curl );
```

However, in some circumstances I clearly see durations of 20 seconds or more eventhough I specified lower time out values for `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`.

How can I make cURL time out at the values I specified?

**UPDATE:**

All the cURL's that take 20 seconds to complete return a "status" of 0. Its probably a DNS problem where it can't resolve the host. I would assume that `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` would take care of this?

Comment: did you tried CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS ?

Comment: I tried `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` set to 5000 but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try reseting Curl "curl_reset($ch);" and than setting timeout

Comment: I tried the `curl_reset`, it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've added an **update** to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code works perfectly.
I've created a simple sleep page, you can check it (gets sleep time as input).

In case that you find cases where the code did not time out, I suggest checking the status code, and to see whether the code got hung on other part (maybe not the curl itself).

```
<?php

     $url = "http://funnify.me/sleep.php?sleep=12"; // time in seconds

     $curlOptions = [
         CURLOPT_URL => $url,
         CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
         CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
         CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
         CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
         CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 8,
         CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 8,
         CURLOPT_NOBODY => TRUE,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
     ];


     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array( $curl, $curlOptions );
     $curlResult = curl_exec( $curl );
     $status = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
     curl_close( $curl );

     echo $status;
?>
```

Cheers,
Ika